# Statement calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

Turn the statement 'either $X$ or $Y$' into an iterated composition.

I'm not sure if my answer is correct, can someone please check for me? :

$$\text{either }X\text{ or }Y \equiv (X\vee Y)\wedge (X\rightarrow (\sim Y))\wedge (Y\rightarrow (\sim X))$$

($\sim$ is negation)

EDIT: Also, can my answer be simplified?

EDIT2: This is now solved, but please feel free to post other solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't be $(X\wedge\sim Y)\vee(\sim X\wedge Y)$?

Comment: Your simplification is correct, and equivalent to what @janmarqz wrote; all expressions indicate that one of $X,Y$ must be true, and one must be false, as it should be.

Comment: I employed the analog's set theory called "symmetric difference": $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Use set theory's 
$$A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A),$$
which is the same as
$$A\triangle B=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B).$$

Comment: comment turned into hint